# Rotationally symmetric manifold with statistical structure

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, information-geometry

Statistical manifolds are riemannian manifolds endowed with an affine torsion-free connection which is not necessarily Levi-Civita but verifies a weaker *compatibility* condition.
More precisely, a statistical manifold $(M,g,\nabla)$ is a Riemannian manifold with a torsion-free *affine* connection $\nabla$ such that $\nabla g$ is symmetric in all entries. Equivalently, there is a dual affine connection $\nabla^*$ such that $X(g(Y,Z)) = g(\nabla_X Y,Z) + g(Y,\nabla^*_X Z)$, with $X,Y,Z \in \mathcal{X}(M)$. Then, the Levi-Civita connection $\hat \nabla$ is related to the other connections by $ \hat \nabla = (\nabla + \nabla^*)/2$. See e.g. [1] for details, other associated tensors and equivalences.

Also from [1], if $M$ is a hypersurface of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ (with standard flat connection $D$), consider the second fundamental form $h$ and the induced connection $\nabla$ in $M$, i.e. we have the tangent and normal decomposition

$$D_{\bar X}(\bar Y) = \nabla_X(Y) + h(X,Y) \nu,$$
where $\nu$ is the unit normal vector field, $X,Y \in \Gamma(TM)$ with local extensions $\bar X, \bar Y \in \mathcal{X}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$, respectively.
If $M$ is *locally strongly convex* then $h$ is definite (definite positive with the suitable choice of normal) and $(M, h, \nabla)$ defines a statistical structure.

A surface of revolution $\Sigma^n$ admits a rotationally symmetric metric $g = dr^2 + f(r)^2 d\theta^2$ in local polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$, $\theta \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. For instance, for constant sectional curvature $K \equiv 0$ take $f(r)=r$ and for $K \equiv 1$ take $f(r)=\sin(r)$.
What are the statistical structures $(h, \nabla)$ and $(h, \nabla^*)$ here? In particular, what is the expression of $h$ as rotationally symmetric (warped) metric? Specifically, what about the case of the sphere?

References

[1] Opozda B., Bochner’s technique for statistical structures, Annals of Global Analysis and Geometry,  volume 48, 357–395 (2015) (https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.06307)